# Server network interface not working properly

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, interface, networkmanager

I recently bought a ZT Openrack server from eBay (the seller mentioned it was a OCP server) planning to use it as a simple file server, and it arrived a few weeks ago. However, it appeared to not connect to the internet, and upon further inspection, the interface was not working.

A few things that I should mention first:

- It has one SFP+ 10GB connection, and an Ethernet connection
- Both the SFP+ and the Ethernet are plugged into a Netgear GS724T switch. The switch works perfectly fine with other computers.
- When the SFP+ is connected, the light next to the port does not light up (possibly indicating a problem with either the cable or the port)
- When the Ethernet is connected, the green light lights up but there
  still is no signal.
- This problem seems to continue throughout the several operating systems I've tried to install.

Here are the operating systems I've installed on the server:

- Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop - What it's currently running
- Ubuntu 20.04 Server
- TrueNAS Core
- Windows 10 Home Edition
- ProxMox Virtual Environment

I've also looked through all of the BIOS settings on the server to no avail.

The outputs of the commands I've tried are below.

`ip link show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp132s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:8c:fa:cf:8c:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Setting the interface to up via `ip link set enp132s0 up` yields these results:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp132s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:8c:fa:cf:8c:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

But it still doesn't work.

`lspci | grep Network`

```
84:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 10 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

`nmcli device show`

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp132s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:8C:FA:CF:8C:90
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

`nmcli connection show`

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  54ead445-75b8-33eb-b656-2520246f6851  ethernet  --
```

Restarting the NetworkManager service with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` and `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager && sudo systemctl start NetworkManager` does absolutely nothing.

I cannot download or install packages easily unless I put **all** of the dependencies on a flash drive and manually install them with `dpkg`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.